# Unable to create subform with table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

i've tried creating a subform (also a subdata sheet).. to be able to track which employee has trained on what document type. I want to be able to run queries/report that i can sort either by employee name or see all employees who trained on a specific document type.

If i have 2 tables, 1 with employee names (only 27 records), and 1 with document types (about 160 records).. how do i create a relationship since the autoID numbers (or primary keys) are not the same amount?

I want to be able to have a form, that displays a datasheet where i can enter employee names and training completion dates. There could be multiple employees who trained on the same document. So far, i've only been able to link 1 employee per 1 document.

Any feedback is very much appreciated!!
Thank you!

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship and requires a third "junction" table. This is basic relational database concept.

Answer (score 0):

This is a many-to-many relationship and requires a third "junction" table: EmpTrng.

Data entry options:

1. one form bound to EmpTrng with comboboxes to select employee and training
2. form/subform arrangement - main form bound to Employees and subform bound to junction table with a combobox to select document
3. form/subform arrangement - main form bound to Documents and subform bound to junction table with a combobox to select employee